# Chart with time series using Rickshaw. format of input data

Tags: javascript, time, d3.js, format, rickshaw

I am willing to draw a chart with `Rickshaw` (`javascript` library working with `D3`).
My data look as follows:

```
var data = [{x : '10:16:00', y : 35.75}, {x : '10:17:00', y : 35.78},  {x : '10:18:00', y : 31.04}];
```

But that just doesn't work with a simple code such as:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.querySelector("#chart"), 
    width: 200, 
    height: 200, 
    series: [{
        color: 'steelblue',
        data: data
    }]
});

graph.render();
```

An error message reads data is indefined. It seems to me the problem is due to my `x`s above being strings and not eg increasing integers.

Do I have to cast the `x`s to some `javascript` time format? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define the `x-axis` as a timeline:

```
var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
    graph: graph,
});
xAxis.render();
```

Then you give your `x` axis data as (for the first one):

```
new Date(2014, 11, 4 , 10, 16, 0, 0).getTime()
```

or using some other `Date` constructor.